# Apply different css on different elements with same attribute

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I have two HTML elements: *element1* and *element2*. They are created dynamically, so I can't use IDs:

```
<element1 class='class1' selected="true" ...[other_attributes]...>
<element1 class='class1' selected="true" ...[other_attributes]...>
<element1 class='class1' selected="false"...[other_attributes]...>
.................................................................
{other <element1> elements}
.................................................................
<element2 class='class2' selected="true" ...[other_attributes]...>
<element2 class='class2' selected="false"...[other_attributes]...>
.................................................................
{other <element2> elements}
```

Now, what I want to do, is to use the same attribute (selected) for element1 and element2, and when selected="true" on element1 to have one css, and when selected="true" on element2 to have different css. Maybe something like:

```
[selected=true]
{
  color.red
}

[selected = true]
{
    color.green
}
```

Except, I want to make it in a way that the HTML will recognize what css to assign on the different element.

I hope I was clear enough.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the same element you're using, this is what `classes` and `IDs` are for:

```
<element id="ID1" class="red" selected="true">
<element id="ID2" class="green" selected="true">
```

Using `IDs`:

```
element#ID1[selected=true]
{
    color:red;
}

element#ID2[selected=true]
{
    color:green;
}
```

Using `classes`:

```
element.red[selected=true]
{
    color:red;
}

element.green[selected=true]
{
    color:green;
}
```

Note that `IDs` must be **unique**, whereas `classes` can be used on as many elements as you like.

**Edit:** Based on your modified question:

```
element.class1[selected=true]
{
    color:red;
}

element.class2[selected=true]
{
    color:green;
}
```

Alternatively you could base it on their parents (if they're different):

```
parent#ID1 element[selected=true] { ... }
parent#ID2 element[selected=true] { ... }
```

Comment: I can't use IDs since the elements are created dynamically (I edited my post). Tnx for the help anyway!

Comment: In your edited question your element1 and element2 have different classes. Simply use `element.class1[selected=true]` and `element.class2[selected=true]`.

Comment: Based on the update by the OP, your answer is definitely the way to go since the classes are already in place.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited since you updated your example code, I've kept my original answer below for reference*

Mix the class and attribute selectors like so:

**HTML**

```
<input class="class1" name="input" />
<input class="class1" />
<input class="class1" name="input" />

<input class="class2" name="input" />
<input class="class2" />
```

**CSS**

```
.class1[name=input]
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.class2[name=input]
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

---

*Original Answer*

In CSS3 you have the `:nth-of-type(n)` selector, used like so:

**HTML**

```
<input name="test" value="First element">

<input name="test" value="Second element">
```

(Note that the example markup above is horrible and should never be done in real life!)

**CSS**

```
<style>

    [name=test]:nth-of-type(1)
    {
        color: red;
    }

    [name=test]:nth-of-type(2)
    {
        color: green;
    }

</style>
```

More info at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: This won't work for me, because this is for same element types but different values. I edited my post. Tnx for the help anyway!

Comment: No worries, updated my answer but its pretty much the same as one already posted it seems :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
element1[selected="true"]
              {
  color:red
}

element2[selected="true"]
             {
color:green
}
```